# How do I set a User field to a SystemUserId in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I'm customizing a form in Microsoft's CRM Dynamics Online, and need to set a field value to the current users's ID. I've got code that correctly pulls the SystemUserID, but I'm having difficulty getting the value into the form field.

```
//Lots of XML/SOAP stuff to pull the user information
var systemUserIdNode = entityNode.selectSingleNode("q1:systemuserid");
crmForm.all.FieldForUserID.DataValue = systemUserIdNode; //Fails silently
```

[Update]
After some digging, I've updated my code based on the sample in the SDK. It now looks like this:

```
var userIdValue = new Array();
userIdValue [0] = new LookupControlItem(systemUserIdNode, 8, fullNameNode);
crmForm.all.new_useridfield.DataValue = userIdValue ;
```

However, this causes an error in the last line - "Object doesn't support this property or method". So I'm still stumped (even more so, as the sample is out of the SDK).

Answer (score 4):

Try getting rid of your first two lines and replacing your third with

```
crmForm.all.new_useridfield.DataValue = 
    [{ 
        id: systemUserIdNode,
        name: fullNameNode,
        typename: 'systemuser'
    }];
```

The id property may require braces, so you might have to change it to:

```
id: '{' + systemUserIdNode + '}'
```